# Finding the value of $k$ such that a constraint of a linear programming problem is redundant?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

A linear programming problem has the following constraints:

$2x+3y\le12$

$kx-5y\le2$

$x\le5$

$x\ge0$, $y\ge0$, $k\ge0$

Find the value of $k$ for which the second constraint is redundant (Doesn’t contribute to the feasible region).

I graphed these on Geogebra, with $k=0.4$.

[image]

I believe the answer is $k<0.4$, however, my book says the answer is $k\le\frac{1}{3}$

Have I made a mistake, if so, where?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what redundant means? The term is new to me. Also are we missing a function that we want to minimize/maximize?

EDIT: Thanks

Comment: I am not interested in actually maximizing an objective function at the moment. What I mean by redundant is that it doesn’t contribute to the feasible region :)

Comment: I agree with you, we define
$$
h(x) = 5y + kx - 2
$$
then the second constraint is redundant if
$$
h(5) = 5y + 5\cdot k - 2 \leq 0 \quad \forall y \geq 0
$$
which happens only if $k \leq \frac{2}{5} = 0.4$

Comment: @Paul But that little triangle is already disallowed by constraint b), thus the line is redundant if the x intercept is greater than $5$.

Comment: @Mikal, you are right.  I guess the answer in the book made the same mistake I did.

Comment: @Mikal, Cool, that was my logic as well, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Take note of $\le$ rather than $<$.

Let $(x,y)$ be a point in the feasible region defined by the other constraints besides the second constraint.

If $0 \le k \le 0.4$, then

$$kx -5y  \le 5k-5y \le 5k\le 2$$

However, if $k>0.4$, then the point $(5,0)$ which satisfy the other constraint would not satisfy the second constraint since

$$k(5)-5(0)=5k>2$$

[image]